# Did I lose my RAID again?

Tags: server, filesystem, raid, data-recovery, mdadm

A little history: 2 years ago I was really excited to find out that mdadm is so powerful that it even can reshape arrays, so you can start with a smaller array and then grow it as you need. I've bought 3x1Tb drives and made a RAID-5. It was fine for a year.

Then I bought 2x more, and tried to reshape to RAID-6 out of 5 drives, and due to some mess with superblock versions, lost all content. Had to rebuild it from scratch, but 2Tb of data were gone.

Yesterday I bought 2 more drives, and this time I had everything: properly built array, UPS. I've disabled write intent map, added 2 new drives as spares and run a command to grow array to 7-disks.

It started working, but speed was ridiculously slow, ~100kb/sec. After processing first 37Mb at such an amazing speed, one of old HDDs fails. I properly shutdown the PC and disconnected the failed drive. After bootup it appeared that it recreated the intent map as it was still in mdadm config, so I removed it from config and rebooted again.

Now all I see is that all mdadm processes deadlock, and don't do anything.

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 1937 root      20   0 12992  608  444 D    0  0.1   0:00.00 mdadm
 2283 root      20   0 12992  852  704 D    0  0.1   0:00.01 mdadm
 2287 root      20   0     0    0    0 D    0  0.0   0:00.01 md0_reshape
 2288 root      18  -2 12992  820  676 D    0  0.1   0:00.01 mdadm
```

And all I see in mdstat is:

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md0 : active raid6 sdb1[1] sdg1[4] sdf1[7] sde1[6] sdd1[0] sdc1[5]
      2929683456 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 1024k chunk, algorithm 2 [7/6] [UU_UUUU]
      [>....................]  reshape =  0.0% (37888/976561152) finish=567604147.2min speed=0K/sec
```

I've already tried mdadm 2.6.7, 3.1.4 and 3.2 - nothing helps. Did I lose my data again? Any suggestions on how can I make this work?

OS is Ubuntu Server 10.04.2.

PS. Needless to say, the data is inaccessible - I cannot mount /dev/md0 to save the most valuable data.

You can see my disappointment - the very specific thing I was excited about failed twice taking 5Tb of my data with it.

**Update:** It appears there is some nice info in kern.log:

```
21:38:48 ...: [  166.522055] raid5: reshape will continue
21:38:48 ...: [  166.522085] raid5: device sdb1 operational as raid disk 1
21:38:48 ...: [  166.522091] raid5: device sdg1 operational as raid disk 4
21:38:48 ...: [  166.522097] raid5: device sdf1 operational as raid disk 5
21:38:48 ...: [  166.522102] raid5: device sde1 operational as raid disk 6
21:38:48 ...: [  166.522107] raid5: device sdd1 operational as raid disk 0
21:38:48 ...: [  166.522111] raid5: device sdc1 operational as raid disk 3
21:38:48 ...: [  166.523942] raid5: allocated 7438kB for md0
21:38:48 ...: [  166.524041] 1: w=1 pa=2 pr=5 m=2 a=2 r=7 op1=0 op2=0
21:38:48 ...: [  166.524050] 4: w=2 pa=2 pr=5 m=2 a=2 r=7 op1=0 op2=0
21:38:48 ...: [  166.524056] 5: w=3 pa=2 pr=5 m=2 a=2 r=7 op1=0 op2=0
21:38:48 ...: [  166.524062] 6: w=4 pa=2 pr=5 m=2 a=2 r=7 op1=0 op2=0
21:38:48 ...: [  166.524068] 0: w=5 pa=2 pr=5 m=2 a=2 r=7 op1=0 op2=0
21:38:48 ...: [  166.524073] 3: w=6 pa=2 pr=5 m=2 a=2 r=7 op1=0 op2=0
21:38:48 ...: [  166.524079] raid5: raid level 6 set md0 active with 6 out of 7 devices, algorithm 2
21:38:48 ...: [  166.524519] RAID5 conf printout:
21:38:48 ...: [  166.524523]  --- rd:7 wd:6
21:38:48 ...: [  166.524528]  disk 0, o:1, dev:sdd1
21:38:48 ...: [  166.524532]  disk 1, o:1, dev:sdb1
21:38:48 ...: [  166.524537]  disk 3, o:1, dev:sdc1
21:38:48 ...: [  166.524541]  disk 4, o:1, dev:sdg1
21:38:48 ...: [  166.524545]  disk 5, o:1, dev:sdf1
21:38:48 ...: [  166.524550]  disk 6, o:1, dev:sde1
21:38:48 ...: [  166.524553] ...ok start reshape thread
21:38:48 ...: [  166.524727] md0: detected capacity change from 0 to 2999995858944
21:38:48 ...: [  166.524735] md: reshape of RAID array md0
21:38:48 ...: [  166.524740] md: minimum _guaranteed_  speed: 1000 KB/sec/disk.
21:38:48 ...: [  166.524745] md: using maximum available idle IO bandwidth (but not more than 200000 KB/sec) for reshape.
21:38:48 ...: [  166.524756] md: using 128k window, over a total of 976561152 blocks.
21:39:05 ...: [  166.525013]  md0:
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520063] INFO: task mdadm:1937 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520068] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520073] mdadm         D 00000000ffffffff     0  1937      1 0x00000000
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520083]  ffff88002ef4f5d8 0000000000000082 0000000000015bc0 0000000000015bc0
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520092]  ffff88002eb5b198 ffff88002ef4ffd8 0000000000015bc0 ffff88002eb5ade0
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520100]  0000000000015bc0 ffff88002ef4ffd8 0000000000015bc0 ffff88002eb5b198
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520107] Call Trace:
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520133]  [<ffffffffa0224892>] get_active_stripe+0x312/0x3f0 [raid456]
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520148]  [<ffffffff81059ae0>] ? default_wake_function+0x0/0x20
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520159]  [<ffffffffa0228413>] make_request+0x243/0x4b0 [raid456]
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520169]  [<ffffffffa0221a90>] ? release_stripe+0x50/0x70 [raid456]
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520179]  [<ffffffff81084790>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520188]  [<ffffffff81414df0>] md_make_request+0xc0/0x130
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520194]  [<ffffffff81414df0>] ? md_make_request+0xc0/0x130
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520205]  [<ffffffff8129f8c1>] generic_make_request+0x1b1/0x4f0
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520214]  [<ffffffff810f6515>] ? mempool_alloc_slab+0x15/0x20
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520222]  [<ffffffff8116c2ec>] ? alloc_buffer_head+0x1c/0x60
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520230]  [<ffffffff8129fc80>] submit_bio+0x80/0x110
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520236]  [<ffffffff8116c849>] submit_bh+0xf9/0x140
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520244]  [<ffffffff8116f124>] block_read_full_page+0x274/0x3b0
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520251]  [<ffffffff81172c90>] ? blkdev_get_block+0x0/0x70
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520258]  [<ffffffff8110d875>] ? __inc_zone_page_state+0x35/0x40
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520265]  [<ffffffff810f46d8>] ? add_to_page_cache_locked+0xe8/0x160
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520272]  [<ffffffff81173d78>] blkdev_readpage+0x18/0x20
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520279]  [<ffffffff810f484b>] __read_cache_page+0x7b/0xe0
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520285]  [<ffffffff81173d60>] ? blkdev_readpage+0x0/0x20
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520290]  [<ffffffff81173d60>] ? blkdev_readpage+0x0/0x20
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520297]  [<ffffffff810f57dc>] do_read_cache_page+0x3c/0x120
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520304]  [<ffffffff810f5909>] read_cache_page_async+0x19/0x20
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520310]  [<ffffffff810f591e>] read_cache_page+0xe/0x20
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520317]  [<ffffffff811a6cb0>] read_dev_sector+0x30/0xa0
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520324]  [<ffffffff811a7fcd>] amiga_partition+0x6d/0x460
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520331]  [<ffffffff811a7938>] check_partition+0x138/0x190
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520338]  [<ffffffff811a7a7a>] rescan_partitions+0xea/0x2f0
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520344]  [<ffffffff811744c7>] __blkdev_get+0x267/0x3d0
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520350]  [<ffffffff81174650>] ? blkdev_open+0x0/0xc0
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520356]  [<ffffffff81174640>] blkdev_get+0x10/0x20
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520362]  [<ffffffff811746c1>] blkdev_open+0x71/0xc0
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520369]  [<ffffffff811419f3>] __dentry_open+0x113/0x370
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520377]  [<ffffffff81253f8f>] ? security_inode_permission+0x1f/0x30
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520385]  [<ffffffff8114de3f>] ? inode_permission+0xaf/0xd0
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520391]  [<ffffffff81141d67>] nameidata_to_filp+0x57/0x70
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520398]  [<ffffffff8115207a>] do_filp_open+0x2da/0xba0
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520406]  [<ffffffff811134a8>] ? unmap_vmas+0x178/0x310
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520414]  [<ffffffff8115dbfa>] ? alloc_fd+0x10a/0x150
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520421]  [<ffffffff81141769>] do_sys_open+0x69/0x170
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520428]  [<ffffffff811418b0>] sys_open+0x20/0x30
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520437]  [<ffffffff810121b2>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520446] INFO: task mdadm:2283 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520450] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520454] mdadm         D 0000000000000000     0  2283   2212 0x00000000
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520462]  ffff88002cca7d98 0000000000000086 0000000000015bc0 0000000000015bc0
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520470]  ffff88002ededf78 ffff88002cca7fd8 0000000000015bc0 ffff88002ededbc0
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520478]  0000000000015bc0 ffff88002cca7fd8 0000000000015bc0 ffff88002ededf78
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520485] Call Trace:
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520495]  [<ffffffff81543a97>] __mutex_lock_slowpath+0xf7/0x180
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520502]  [<ffffffff8154397b>] mutex_lock+0x2b/0x50
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520508]  [<ffffffff8117404d>] __blkdev_put+0x3d/0x190
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520514]  [<ffffffff811741b0>] blkdev_put+0x10/0x20
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520520]  [<ffffffff811741f3>] blkdev_close+0x33/0x60
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520527]  [<ffffffff81145375>] __fput+0xf5/0x210
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520534]  [<ffffffff811454b5>] fput+0x25/0x30
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520540]  [<ffffffff811415ad>] filp_close+0x5d/0x90
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520546]  [<ffffffff81141697>] sys_close+0xb7/0x120
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520553]  [<ffffffff810121b2>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520559] INFO: task md0_reshape:2287 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520563] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520567] md0_reshape   D ffff88003aee96f0     0  2287      2 0x00000000
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520575]  ffff88003cf05a70 0000000000000046 0000000000015bc0 0000000000015bc0
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520582]  ffff88003aee9aa8 ffff88003cf05fd8 0000000000015bc0 ffff88003aee96f0
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520590]  0000000000015bc0 ffff88003cf05fd8 0000000000015bc0 ffff88003aee9aa8
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520597] Call Trace:
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520608]  [<ffffffffa0224892>] get_active_stripe+0x312/0x3f0 [raid456]
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520616]  [<ffffffff81059ae0>] ? default_wake_function+0x0/0x20
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520626]  [<ffffffffa0226f80>] reshape_request+0x4c0/0x9a0 [raid456]
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520634]  [<ffffffff81084790>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520644]  [<ffffffffa022777a>] sync_request+0x31a/0x3a0 [raid456]
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520651]  [<ffffffff81052713>] ? __wake_up+0x53/0x70
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520658]  [<ffffffff814156b1>] md_do_sync+0x621/0xbb0
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520668]  [<ffffffff810387b9>] ? default_spin_lock_flags+0x9/0x10
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520675]  [<ffffffff8141640c>] md_thread+0x5c/0x130
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520681]  [<ffffffff81084790>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520688]  [<ffffffff814163b0>] ? md_thread+0x0/0x130
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520694]  [<ffffffff81084416>] kthread+0x96/0xa0
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520701]  [<ffffffff810131ea>] child_rip+0xa/0x20
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520707]  [<ffffffff81084380>] ? kthread+0x0/0xa0
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520713]  [<ffffffff810131e0>] ? child_rip+0x0/0x20
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520718] INFO: task mdadm:2288 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520721] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520725] mdadm         D 0000000000000000     0  2288      1 0x00000000
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520733]  ffff88002cca9c18 0000000000000086 0000000000015bc0 0000000000015bc0
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520741]  ffff88003aee83b8 ffff88002cca9fd8 0000000000015bc0 ffff88003aee8000
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520748]  0000000000015bc0 ffff88002cca9fd8 0000000000015bc0 ffff88003aee83b8
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520755] Call Trace:
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520763]  [<ffffffff81543a97>] __mutex_lock_slowpath+0xf7/0x180
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520771]  [<ffffffff812a6d50>] ? exact_match+0x0/0x10
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520777]  [<ffffffff8154397b>] mutex_lock+0x2b/0x50
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520783]  [<ffffffff811742c8>] __blkdev_get+0x68/0x3d0
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520790]  [<ffffffff81174650>] ? blkdev_open+0x0/0xc0
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520795]  [<ffffffff81174640>] blkdev_get+0x10/0x20
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520801]  [<ffffffff811746c1>] blkdev_open+0x71/0xc0
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520808]  [<ffffffff811419f3>] __dentry_open+0x113/0x370
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520815]  [<ffffffff81253f8f>] ? security_inode_permission+0x1f/0x30
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520821]  [<ffffffff8114de3f>] ? inode_permission+0xaf/0xd0
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520828]  [<ffffffff81141d67>] nameidata_to_filp+0x57/0x70
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520834]  [<ffffffff8115207a>] do_filp_open+0x2da/0xba0
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520841]  [<ffffffff810ff0e1>] ? lru_cache_add_lru+0x21/0x40
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520848]  [<ffffffff8111109c>] ? do_anonymous_page+0x11c/0x330
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520855]  [<ffffffff81115d5f>] ? handle_mm_fault+0x31f/0x3c0
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520862]  [<ffffffff8115dbfa>] ? alloc_fd+0x10a/0x150
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520868]  [<ffffffff81141769>] do_sys_open+0x69/0x170
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520874]  [<ffffffff811418b0>] sys_open+0x20/0x30
21:42:04 ...: [  362.520882]  [<ffffffff810121b2>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520065] INFO: task mdadm:1937 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520071] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520077] mdadm         D 00000000ffffffff     0  1937      1 0x00000000
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520087]  ffff88002ef4f5d8 0000000000000082 0000000000015bc0 0000000000015bc0
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520096]  ffff88002eb5b198 ffff88002ef4ffd8 0000000000015bc0 ffff88002eb5ade0
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520104]  0000000000015bc0 ffff88002ef4ffd8 0000000000015bc0 ffff88002eb5b198
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520112] Call Trace:
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520139]  [<ffffffffa0224892>] get_active_stripe+0x312/0x3f0 [raid456]
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520154]  [<ffffffff81059ae0>] ? default_wake_function+0x0/0x20
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520165]  [<ffffffffa0228413>] make_request+0x243/0x4b0 [raid456]
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520175]  [<ffffffffa0221a90>] ? release_stripe+0x50/0x70 [raid456]
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520185]  [<ffffffff81084790>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520194]  [<ffffffff81414df0>] md_make_request+0xc0/0x130
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520201]  [<ffffffff81414df0>] ? md_make_request+0xc0/0x130
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520212]  [<ffffffff8129f8c1>] generic_make_request+0x1b1/0x4f0
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520221]  [<ffffffff810f6515>] ? mempool_alloc_slab+0x15/0x20
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520229]  [<ffffffff8116c2ec>] ? alloc_buffer_head+0x1c/0x60
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520237]  [<ffffffff8129fc80>] submit_bio+0x80/0x110
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520244]  [<ffffffff8116c849>] submit_bh+0xf9/0x140
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520252]  [<ffffffff8116f124>] block_read_full_page+0x274/0x3b0
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520258]  [<ffffffff81172c90>] ? blkdev_get_block+0x0/0x70
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520266]  [<ffffffff8110d875>] ? __inc_zone_page_state+0x35/0x40
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520273]  [<ffffffff810f46d8>] ? add_to_page_cache_locked+0xe8/0x160
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520280]  [<ffffffff81173d78>] blkdev_readpage+0x18/0x20
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520286]  [<ffffffff810f484b>] __read_cache_page+0x7b/0xe0
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520293]  [<ffffffff81173d60>] ? blkdev_readpage+0x0/0x20
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520299]  [<ffffffff81173d60>] ? blkdev_readpage+0x0/0x20
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520306]  [<ffffffff810f57dc>] do_read_cache_page+0x3c/0x120
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520313]  [<ffffffff810f5909>] read_cache_page_async+0x19/0x20
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520319]  [<ffffffff810f591e>] read_cache_page+0xe/0x20
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520327]  [<ffffffff811a6cb0>] read_dev_sector+0x30/0xa0
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520334]  [<ffffffff811a7fcd>] amiga_partition+0x6d/0x460
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520341]  [<ffffffff811a7938>] check_partition+0x138/0x190
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520348]  [<ffffffff811a7a7a>] rescan_partitions+0xea/0x2f0
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520355]  [<ffffffff811744c7>] __blkdev_get+0x267/0x3d0
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520361]  [<ffffffff81174650>] ? blkdev_open+0x0/0xc0
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520367]  [<ffffffff81174640>] blkdev_get+0x10/0x20
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520373]  [<ffffffff811746c1>] blkdev_open+0x71/0xc0
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520380]  [<ffffffff811419f3>] __dentry_open+0x113/0x370
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520388]  [<ffffffff81253f8f>] ? security_inode_permission+0x1f/0x30
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520396]  [<ffffffff8114de3f>] ? inode_permission+0xaf/0xd0
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520403]  [<ffffffff81141d67>] nameidata_to_filp+0x57/0x70
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520410]  [<ffffffff8115207a>] do_filp_open+0x2da/0xba0
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520417]  [<ffffffff811134a8>] ? unmap_vmas+0x178/0x310
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520426]  [<ffffffff8115dbfa>] ? alloc_fd+0x10a/0x150
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520432]  [<ffffffff81141769>] do_sys_open+0x69/0x170
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520438]  [<ffffffff811418b0>] sys_open+0x20/0x30
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520447]  [<ffffffff810121b2>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520458] INFO: task mdadm:2283 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520462] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520467] mdadm         D 0000000000000000     0  2283   2212 0x00000000
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520475]  ffff88002cca7d98 0000000000000086 0000000000015bc0 0000000000015bc0
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520483]  ffff88002ededf78 ffff88002cca7fd8 0000000000015bc0 ffff88002ededbc0
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520490]  0000000000015bc0 ffff88002cca7fd8 0000000000015bc0 ffff88002ededf78
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520498] Call Trace:
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520508]  [<ffffffff81543a97>] __mutex_lock_slowpath+0xf7/0x180
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520515]  [<ffffffff8154397b>] mutex_lock+0x2b/0x50
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520521]  [<ffffffff8117404d>] __blkdev_put+0x3d/0x190
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520527]  [<ffffffff811741b0>] blkdev_put+0x10/0x20
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520533]  [<ffffffff811741f3>] blkdev_close+0x33/0x60
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520541]  [<ffffffff81145375>] __fput+0xf5/0x210
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520547]  [<ffffffff811454b5>] fput+0x25/0x30
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520554]  [<ffffffff811415ad>] filp_close+0x5d/0x90
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520560]  [<ffffffff81141697>] sys_close+0xb7/0x120
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520568]  [<ffffffff810121b2>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520574] INFO: task md0_reshape:2287 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520578] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520582] md0_reshape   D ffff88003aee96f0     0  2287      2 0x00000000
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520590]  ffff88003cf05a70 0000000000000046 0000000000015bc0 0000000000015bc0
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520597]  ffff88003aee9aa8 ffff88003cf05fd8 0000000000015bc0 ffff88003aee96f0
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520605]  0000000000015bc0 ffff88003cf05fd8 0000000000015bc0 ffff88003aee9aa8
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520612] Call Trace:
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520623]  [<ffffffffa0224892>] get_active_stripe+0x312/0x3f0 [raid456]
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520633]  [<ffffffff81059ae0>] ? default_wake_function+0x0/0x20
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520643]  [<ffffffffa0226f80>] reshape_request+0x4c0/0x9a0 [raid456]
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520651]  [<ffffffff81084790>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520661]  [<ffffffffa022777a>] sync_request+0x31a/0x3a0 [raid456]
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520668]  [<ffffffff81052713>] ? __wake_up+0x53/0x70
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520675]  [<ffffffff814156b1>] md_do_sync+0x621/0xbb0
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520685]  [<ffffffff810387b9>] ? default_spin_lock_flags+0x9/0x10
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520692]  [<ffffffff8141640c>] md_thread+0x5c/0x130
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520699]  [<ffffffff81084790>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520705]  [<ffffffff814163b0>] ? md_thread+0x0/0x130
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520711]  [<ffffffff81084416>] kthread+0x96/0xa0
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520718]  [<ffffffff810131ea>] child_rip+0xa/0x20
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520725]  [<ffffffff81084380>] ? kthread+0x0/0xa0
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520730]  [<ffffffff810131e0>] ? child_rip+0x0/0x20
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520735] INFO: task mdadm:2288 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520739] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520743] mdadm         D 0000000000000000     0  2288      1 0x00000000
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520751]  ffff88002cca9c18 0000000000000086 0000000000015bc0 0000000000015bc0
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520759]  ffff88003aee83b8 ffff88002cca9fd8 0000000000015bc0 ffff88003aee8000
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520767]  0000000000015bc0 ffff88002cca9fd8 0000000000015bc0 ffff88003aee83b8
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520774] Call Trace:
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520782]  [<ffffffff81543a97>] __mutex_lock_slowpath+0xf7/0x180
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520790]  [<ffffffff812a6d50>] ? exact_match+0x0/0x10
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520797]  [<ffffffff8154397b>] mutex_lock+0x2b/0x50
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520804]  [<ffffffff811742c8>] __blkdev_get+0x68/0x3d0
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520810]  [<ffffffff81174650>] ? blkdev_open+0x0/0xc0
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520816]  [<ffffffff81174640>] blkdev_get+0x10/0x20
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520822]  [<ffffffff811746c1>] blkdev_open+0x71/0xc0
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520829]  [<ffffffff811419f3>] __dentry_open+0x113/0x370
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520837]  [<ffffffff81253f8f>] ? security_inode_permission+0x1f/0x30
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520843]  [<ffffffff8114de3f>] ? inode_permission+0xaf/0xd0
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520850]  [<ffffffff81141d67>] nameidata_to_filp+0x57/0x70
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520857]  [<ffffffff8115207a>] do_filp_open+0x2da/0xba0
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520864]  [<ffffffff810ff0e1>] ? lru_cache_add_lru+0x21/0x40
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520871]  [<ffffffff8111109c>] ? do_anonymous_page+0x11c/0x330
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520878]  [<ffffffff81115d5f>] ? handle_mm_fault+0x31f/0x3c0
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520885]  [<ffffffff8115dbfa>] ? alloc_fd+0x10a/0x150
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520891]  [<ffffffff81141769>] do_sys_open+0x69/0x170
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520897]  [<ffffffff811418b0>] sys_open+0x20/0x30
21:44:04 ...: [  482.520905]  [<ffffffff810121b2>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520053] INFO: task mdadm:1937 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520059] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520065] mdadm         D 00000000ffffffff     0  1937      1 0x00000000
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520075]  ffff88002ef4f5d8 0000000000000082 0000000000015bc0 0000000000015bc0
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520084]  ffff88002eb5b198 ffff88002ef4ffd8 0000000000015bc0 ffff88002eb5ade0
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520091]  0000000000015bc0 ffff88002ef4ffd8 0000000000015bc0 ffff88002eb5b198
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520099] Call Trace:
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520127]  [<ffffffffa0224892>] get_active_stripe+0x312/0x3f0 [raid456]
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520142]  [<ffffffff81059ae0>] ? default_wake_function+0x0/0x20
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520153]  [<ffffffffa0228413>] make_request+0x243/0x4b0 [raid456]
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520162]  [<ffffffffa0221a90>] ? release_stripe+0x50/0x70 [raid456]
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520171]  [<ffffffff81084790>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520180]  [<ffffffff81414df0>] md_make_request+0xc0/0x130
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520187]  [<ffffffff81414df0>] ? md_make_request+0xc0/0x130
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520197]  [<ffffffff8129f8c1>] generic_make_request+0x1b1/0x4f0
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520206]  [<ffffffff810f6515>] ? mempool_alloc_slab+0x15/0x20
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520215]  [<ffffffff8116c2ec>] ? alloc_buffer_head+0x1c/0x60
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520222]  [<ffffffff8129fc80>] submit_bio+0x80/0x110
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520229]  [<ffffffff8116c849>] submit_bh+0xf9/0x140
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520237]  [<ffffffff8116f124>] block_read_full_page+0x274/0x3b0
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520244]  [<ffffffff81172c90>] ? blkdev_get_block+0x0/0x70
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520252]  [<ffffffff8110d875>] ? __inc_zone_page_state+0x35/0x40
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520259]  [<ffffffff810f46d8>] ? add_to_page_cache_locked+0xe8/0x160
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520266]  [<ffffffff81173d78>] blkdev_readpage+0x18/0x20
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520273]  [<ffffffff810f484b>] __read_cache_page+0x7b/0xe0
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520279]  [<ffffffff81173d60>] ? blkdev_readpage+0x0/0x20
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520285]  [<ffffffff81173d60>] ? blkdev_readpage+0x0/0x20
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520292]  [<ffffffff810f57dc>] do_read_cache_page+0x3c/0x120
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520300]  [<ffffffff810f5909>] read_cache_page_async+0x19/0x20
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520306]  [<ffffffff810f591e>] read_cache_page+0xe/0x20
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520314]  [<ffffffff811a6cb0>] read_dev_sector+0x30/0xa0
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520321]  [<ffffffff811a7fcd>] amiga_partition+0x6d/0x460
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520328]  [<ffffffff811a7938>] check_partition+0x138/0x190
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520335]  [<ffffffff811a7a7a>] rescan_partitions+0xea/0x2f0
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520342]  [<ffffffff811744c7>] __blkdev_get+0x267/0x3d0
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520348]  [<ffffffff81174650>] ? blkdev_open+0x0/0xc0
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520354]  [<ffffffff81174640>] blkdev_get+0x10/0x20
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520359]  [<ffffffff811746c1>] blkdev_open+0x71/0xc0
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520367]  [<ffffffff811419f3>] __dentry_open+0x113/0x370
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520375]  [<ffffffff81253f8f>] ? security_inode_permission+0x1f/0x30
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520383]  [<ffffffff8114de3f>] ? inode_permission+0xaf/0xd0
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520390]  [<ffffffff81141d67>] nameidata_to_filp+0x57/0x70
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520397]  [<ffffffff8115207a>] do_filp_open+0x2da/0xba0
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520404]  [<ffffffff811134a8>] ? unmap_vmas+0x178/0x310
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520413]  [<ffffffff8115dbfa>] ? alloc_fd+0x10a/0x150
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520419]  [<ffffffff81141769>] do_sys_open+0x69/0x170
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520425]  [<ffffffff811418b0>] sys_open+0x20/0x30
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520434]  [<ffffffff810121b2>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520443] INFO: task mdadm:2283 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520447] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520451] mdadm         D 0000000000000000     0  2283   2212 0x00000000
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520460]  ffff88002cca7d98 0000000000000086 0000000000015bc0 0000000000015bc0
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520468]  ffff88002ededf78 ffff88002cca7fd8 0000000000015bc0 ffff88002ededbc0
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520475]  0000000000015bc0 ffff88002cca7fd8 0000000000015bc0 ffff88002ededf78
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520483] Call Trace:
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520492]  [<ffffffff81543a97>] __mutex_lock_slowpath+0xf7/0x180
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520500]  [<ffffffff8154397b>] mutex_lock+0x2b/0x50
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520506]  [<ffffffff8117404d>] __blkdev_put+0x3d/0x190
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520512]  [<ffffffff811741b0>] blkdev_put+0x10/0x20
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520518]  [<ffffffff811741f3>] blkdev_close+0x33/0x60
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520526]  [<ffffffff81145375>] __fput+0xf5/0x210
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520533]  [<ffffffff811454b5>] fput+0x25/0x30
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520539]  [<ffffffff811415ad>] filp_close+0x5d/0x90
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520545]  [<ffffffff81141697>] sys_close+0xb7/0x120
21:46:04 ...: [  602.520552]  [<ffffffff810121b2>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to contact Neil Brown (THE developer), and he immidiately suggested to increase stripe_cache_size to 2048 at least. That resembles my previous question where I was unable to make that setting permanent.

So after setting it 8192 reshape continued, so problem is solved.
God bless Neil Brown :-)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a reshaping will sit at speed=0K/sec because the backup file failed to be created, or was lost during the processing.

The solution, in this case, was supplied by Neil Brown in response to an email to [linux-raid@vger.kernel.org](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.raid/43942).

> You should be able to simply stop the array and re-assemble with a different
>   backup file and the magic flag  "--invalid-backup" (required mdadm 3.2 or
>   later).
>
> The backup-file is only really needed in case of a crash.  As you will stop
>   the array cleanly  there will be no need to recover anything when you
>   re-assemble, so --invalid-backup (Which say "there is nothing in the backup
>   file, but that is OK) is perfectly safe.
>
> NeilBrown

---

For a RAID5, as device `/dev/md0`, with 7 disk mounted at `/mnt/data`; 
the procedure to his answer is:

*All of the following commands must be run as root or equivalent.*

Find any open connections to the drive:

```
lsof /mnt/data
```

Close them, or stop services that may be interacting with it.
Commonly:

```
systemctl stop <SERVICE_NAME>
```

or

```
service <SERVICE_NAME> stop
```

Unmount, stop, and then reassemble:

```
umount /mnt/data
mdadm --stop /dev/md0
mdadm --assemble --invalid-backup --backup-file=/root/mdadm0.bak /dev/md0 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1 /dev/sdf1 /dev/sdg1 /dev/sdh1 /dev/sdi1
```

Depending on prior configurations, the device may automatically remount after the assembly command. If not, mount with:

```
mount /dev/md0 /mnt/data
```

It is then safe to restart any services or connections running off of there.